# Changing values of nested interfaces with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I want to create an app that can update an imported nested config file (similar to swagger).

I created an json config file, and generated interfaces for it with the help of https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript

Then i import the original json config file, convert it to nested interface and pass it to the `useState` hook. The question is, how can i update single values from the app?

**interfaces.ts**

```
export interface Config {
  project_info: ProjectInfo
  modules: Module[]
}

export interface ProjectInfo {
  go_version: number
  name: string
  port: number
}
```

**Homepage.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from "react"
import { Module, Endpoint, UrlParam, Body, Config, ProjectInfo } from "../interfaces"
import Header from "./Header"

import json_config from "../../../config.json"

export const Homepage = () => {

  // used to filter the selected module
  const [currentlySelectedModule, setCurrentlySelectedModule] = useState("")

  // import json file and convert it to the nested interface
  const placeholder_config: Config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_config))

  // convert the imported json config to hook, that has the form of generated interface
  const [config, setConfig] = useState<Config>(placeholder_config)

  return (

          <div className="code py-14 grid gap-14 mb-30">
            <div>
              <div className="fs-7 fw-700">ProjectInfo</div>
              <div className="">
                <div>project_name :{config.project_info.name}</div>
                <div>
                  project_name:
                  <input
                    className="module__endpoint_value_input endpoint__input_url"
                    value={config.project_info.name}
                    type="text"
                    // onChange={(e) => setConfig((e) => (config.project_info.name = e.target.value))}
                    // onChange={(e) => setPlaceholderConfig(() => config.project_info.name = e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>go_version :{config.project_info.go_version}</div>
                <div>port :{config.project_info.port}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
)
}
```

So i'm sending the whole config file down, but want to change nested interface values.

How can i update `ProjectInfo.name` in this case?
Additionally, is `useState` the best hook for this case?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two considerable mistakes in your code:

- Callback passed to `setConfig` is not returning new config
- State is **mutated** inside this callback

You can implement custom hook for your config like this:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

function useConfig(props) {
    const [config, setConfig] = useState(props.config);

    // Setter for config.project_info.name
    // for other properties there should be other setters
    const setProjectName = (name) => {
        setConfig((config) => ({
            // Should copy every level of data structure manually
            ...config,
            project_info: {
                ...config.project_info,
                name
            }
        }))
    }

    return {
        config,
        setProjectName
    }
}
```

And then use it in your component:

```js
import json_config from "../../../config.json"

const Homepage = () => {
    const { config, setProjectName } = useConfig({ config: json_config });

    const handleNameChange = (event) => {
        setProjectName(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            value={config.project_info.name}
            onChange={handleNameChange}
        />
    )
}
```

If you don't want to copy deep nested objects manually, you could use libraries like [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/), which allows you to write "mutating" code, but not actually mutate it. Other option is to use reactive state management library like [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html).